# Rails background image upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, delayed-job, carrierwave, background-process

I'm using "carrierwave" gem for uploading image files and also "carrierwave backgrounder" to process the uploading + processing the image with RMagick in the background (I use Delayed Job for this).

Everything works like a charm. Except one thing - I want to upload the images and show them right under the upload form (so ,everything happens on the same page). So, basically, what happens - since the uploading and image-processing are relatively slow, by the time the page has been rendered after the posting - the image itself is not yet ready: so image_tag shows broken "assets" link (href = "assets"). After waiting 2-3 seconds (couple of refreshes), the image appears on the screen.

So, my question would be - can I somehow show the "*LOADING*" animation (or text, or another picture - doesn't matter) **instead** of broken (not yet available) image, and once it is ready - to display the image to the user. Can this be done without AJAX ? Or should I consider re-doing it with AJAX ?

Sorry for the long story. Hope for your help!

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: There is a railscast describing this exact scenario, it is a pro version but it's worth $9 in my opinion. http://railscasts.com

Comment: Eh. What episode is it ?

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes/383-uploading-to-amazon-s3

Comment: Thank you for the info. I'll certainly take a look at it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution is pretty simple: I observe if I have any images containing "tmp" field in the database (s.t tmp != null). If so - they are being processed in the background, so I use setInterval function, that keeps asking if tmp is null or not: Once it is null - processing is done for sure. if not - loading animation is running instead of the uploaded image. Quite simple.

Answer (score 1):

You have different way of achieving this :

One is to use https://github.com/lardawge/carrierwave_backgrounder , so you'll know if the image is being processed with the new column it uses.

You could also use the JS File API as described here : http://kellishaver.tumblr.com/post/21428272282/using-the-file-api-to-preview-images-before-uploading

And I guess there are other options.